# Check MouseButtonState in loop

Tags: c#, winforms

To get you more into what I am trying, I'll try to give you an example:

In Google Maps you can hold down you mouse button and drag through the entire world.
I've reached the same state, but to run it more smooth, I build a `for` loop around it.

Looks like this:

```
   private void pictureBoxMap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.mouseDown)
        {
            int frames = 64;

            PointF vector = new PointF();

            vector.X = (e.X - Cursor.Position.X) / frames;
            vector.Y = (e.Y - Cursor.Position.Y) / frames;

            for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            {
                //Determines the X and Y into coordinates and slowly render
                //the map. Looks smooth.
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, somehow I need to escape that loop and manage to check if the Mouse is still hold down.

Here is my `Mouse_Down` Event:

```
    private void pictureBoxMap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        this.mouseDown = true;
    }
```

Is there any possible propertie or method to call and check the current mouse state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)` in `MouseMove` event handler. You can remove `mouseDown` field.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov That would save me a bool, but it gets what button was pressed last. It will still loop.

Comment: What about replacing your for loop with a while loop using recursion. That way it could do its task, call itself which then checks if the button is still pressed and escapes the loop if it isnt

Comment: @Takarii wouldn't that be the same as mentioned above? It still would search for the last pressed Button. But Ben already found a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function for the [left mouse button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.leftbutton(v=vs.110).aspx).  The link has a menu on the left side of the screen that shows properties for the other buttons.

Comment: Did you add a reference to PresentationCore to your project?

Comment: No ... I din't. Thank you very much. It works as it should!